# How to mount FSx Lustre in read only mode?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-fsx, lustre

I have S3 data I'd like to mount via AWS FSx Lustre, and this data should only be read. Which additional flags, or changes, do I need beyond the default mount command

```
sudo mount -t lustre -o noatime,flock DNS_NAME@tcp:/MOUNT_POINT /fsx
```

Answer (score 1):

No point in setting noatime on a read-only mount. So...

```
sudo mount -t lustre -o ro,flock DNS_NAME@tcp:/MOUNT_POINT /fsx
```

(not tested)

Comment: If you can control the server side, you could create a nodemap that forces all client mounts within a specific IP range to be read-only, but I don't think that is possible with FSX.

Comment: Is `ro` the only flag that's required? Anything else more lustre specific I should do?